# What is the appropriate analysis method to test for differences between respondents' answer-profiles?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multivariate-analysis, categorical-encoding, correspondence-analysis

I am going to collect data from 8 people (T1, T2,..., T8) who each give reasons (a,b,c,d,...) for about 2000 decisions (O1,O2,O3,...,O2000). The decisions are binary (1 or 0). The reasons are from a fixed list of about 30 reasons, and for each decision the people can use as many of these reasons as they want but each reason at most once per decision. This would result in data like the following:

[image: example table of data]

I have two related questions about this:

(1) I want to test whether the 8 people (T1,T2,...) have significantly different 'profiles' in the sense of the kinds of reasons they tend to use for their decisions (taking into account the difference between deciding 1 or 0). Which method of analysis and test should I use for this?

(2) Is it possible to characterize these profiles using the reasons (a,b,c,...) they give?

Comment: I don't know about tests (and you would need a better(more precise formulated hypothesis). But to characterize response profiles, I would start with correspondence analysis, search this site. If there are less than eight eigenvalues not approximately series, not all profiles can be different ...

Comment: Thanks, I'll start reading up there. The hypothesis would be that each profile is distinct from all others, so I suppose many tests would be needed.